# Redirect to previous page after login using Node js

Tags: node.js

I would like to redirect the user to the previous page that they want to view (which needs authentication before viewing) after logging in. How can I do that?
For example, a user goes to a URI "/account" that needs an authentication, so probably if they are not logged in, it will directly go to login page but once they login, I want them be directed to "/account" instead of "/" which renders the index page.
Thanks

Comment: Use res.redirect('/yourPage'). I cannot comment more, unless I see your code.

Comment: Where do you need help? Which technologies do you use? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use `var prevPage = req.originalUrl` to save the URL from where the user will be coming from, this is the previous page that you would want to redirect the user later, once you are done with the current middleware simply use `` res.redirect(`${prevPage}`) `` to send the user back to that same page..